# Angular material progress bar loader

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm adding a progress bar to my project but it's not working properly.

here is my loader.service code.

```
  public isLoading : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
```

here is my interceptor.services code

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor( public loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(
        () => {
          this.loaderService.isLoading.next(false);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

html page

```
    <div class="loader-container">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading | async" ></mat-progress-bar>
  </div>
```

any one please check what's the issue with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your interceptor to providers in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { InterceptorService } from './interceptors';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's your `service.interptor.ts`

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor( public loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(
        () => {
          this.loaderService.isLoading.next(false);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here's your template file

```
<div class="loader-container">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading | async" ></mat-progress-bar>
  </div>
```

Lastly, here's your `component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Khumo Mogorosi, But I already added an interceptor to provider in app.module.ts file still not working